# UIScrollview inside UIpageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using `UIPageViewController` with curl effect to enable horizontal swiping b/w view controllers.However the content size is bigger than the height of view's.so i added `UIScrollView` in my view controller to support vertical scrolling.I added this code in viewcontroller to set content size of scroll view-

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 900)];
}
```

The problem is that when the view controller is loaded in `UIPageViewController` the scroll view doesn't scroll initially when i try to scroll it, but it scroll once i load next controller(by horizontal swipe) and returns back to the first view controller.
What is i'm doing wrong? Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the issue solved.Just add this snippet

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Thats all!